# HTML Email Spacing - Outlook in 120 DPI

Tags: html, outlook

I am working on a template for HTML Mailings. At the moment I have a well constructed template with almost no errors.

Due to the default scaling in W10 (125%), I need the template to render nicelye in Outlook 120 dpi mode. However this is where I am struggling.

The 2 images added to the post show the problem. A small clickable grey line appears at some tables.

Any suggestions.
[Unclicked Table space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5Fvd.png)
[Clicked Table Space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uspaD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was that the tables were not enclosed in a single 100% width table. By nesting the content of the mail in a  and  the issue is prevented.

Nesting of tables is key.

The implementation can be found on my Github.
Link: https://github.com/Tom-Br/HTML-MailTemplate